# UNIX - With egrep, how to filter to patterns occuring n times?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Title says it all, I need to filter a file with egrep that has specifications, but the one I can't figure out is to make sure that it occurs 3 times. (Direct wording from problem - contains a word of 5 or more characters, which occurs at least three times in the line)

Comment: Thanks to provide sample input/output

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I can't figure out how to check if it meets the number of occurences while running grep. So far I have                                                                              \\ egrep '\b[a-zA-Z]{5}\b'.*
Which covers everything else I need, but I need to be able to filter it to words that occur atleast 3 times

Comment: Looks vaguely similar to:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53528/using-grep-command-and-backreferencing

Comment: You mean the *same* word appearing three times? Or is three different words allowed?

Comment: The same word three times. Different words may be in the line.

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
egrep '([a-zA-Z]{5}).*\1.*\1'
```

This works in my quick testing, but I'm not sure how robust it is

`\1` (and `\2`, `\3`...) are *back-references*. I placed `(` and `)` around the pattern for five letters, `[a-zA-Z]`, and this that is referred to as the first *capture group*. `\1` then means that the regex expects to find a repeat of the same word that matched within the first `(`-`)` group.

Finally, there is a `.*` in between the three words, to allows anything to appear between them

Comment: Can you explain the \1 's?

Comment: @KenP Look up "back references" in any regular expression tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (not tested) :

```
awk '
  /\b[a-zA-Z]{5}\b/{
    matches[$0]++
  }
  END{
    for (m in matches) {
      if (matches[m] >= 3) {print m}
    }
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
abc abc abc should not match
totally this line should totally match, isn't it? totally 
Title: word with 5 letters like title should also match, given title is present 3 or more times
this line should not totally match, total only partly matches with totally
```

To match words with matching case:

```
$ grep -wE '([a-zA-Z]{5,}).*\1.*\1' ip.txt 
totally this line should totally match, isn't it? totally
```

To match words regardless of case:

```
$ grep -iwE '([a-zA-Z]{5,}).*\1.*\1' ip.txt 
totally this line should totally match, isn't it? totally 
Title: word with 5 letters like title should also match, given title is present 3 or more times
```

To match any sequence of five or more letters:

```
$ grep -iE '([a-zA-Z]{5,}).*\1.*\1' ip.txt 
totally this line should totally match, isn't it? totally 
Title: word with 5 letters like title should also match, given title is present 3 or more times
this line should not totally match, total only partly matches with totally
```

- `-E` extended regular expression
- `-w` match whole words only
- `-i` ignore case
- `[a-zA-Z]{5,}` lower or upper case letters, five or more times
- `()` capture group and `\1` is back-reference to it

and a bit of fun if you have `pcre` regex

```
$ echo 'totally title match' | grep -P '([a-zA-Z]{5,}).*(?1).*(?1)'
totally title match
```

- `(?1)` refers to the regex pattern `([a-zA-Z]{5,})` itself

Comment: Thank you very much! Got quite close but just couldn't put it all together. Cheers :)

Comment: @KenP glad it helped, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help in general :)